# Death as a key flaw in existence -- where is this from?

Tags: tanach, midrash

I recall learning at one point the idea to effect: Death is the key imperfection in human existence

What are the sources under this?

Comment: As Gabriel answers, the world was "very good" - no imperfection. The Torah says that the punishment for eating the fruit would be, You shall surely die. There are lots of other knock-on consequences, but that is the basic result of their sin.

Answer (score 1):

Death was not supposed to exist at all, until Adam and Chava ate from the tree.

This is parallel to the Jews not supposed to exist after Mattan Tora until the golden caff.

Meam Loez (Genesis I)
Meam Loez (Genesis II)

In this context the population was never supposed to be eight  billion, Mashiach was not even part of the plan.
How do we know this, following logic, If Adam was supposed to live infinitely, then too his kids, the population would be around the tens of millions, the amount of space on earth, the only reason we are able to keep populating is because spots keep opening every 75 years or so, and at times sooner.

Another opinion would be, no, just two, Adam and Chava because we all lived through them.

Why was mashiach not involved in the first place, simple, if man never sinned, then there would be no reason for a savior, they would be living like robots until the time runs up for the planet.

Unfortunately in our time, this is not the case, so we have to deal with death, and disappointment.

I would highly recommend to invest in the meam loez series, it will answer ninety-nine percent of your questions and even share with you some insight on parts of the Tora that's not mainstream.   Everyone approves of the author and its contents.

Good luck.

Comment: in the 2nd posuk madras rabba says that  וְר֣וּחַ אֱלֹהִ֔ים מְרַחֶ֖פֶת עַל־פְּנֵ֥י הַמָּֽיִם is a referance to moshiach so even in the context of Adam and Chava before the sin there was the concept of moshiach.

Comment: @dude, I would like to note, the Tora that we have is viewed  by many to what is called Plan B, not the original Tora set by hashems initial idea of creation. The first Tora should have started with an Aleph not a Bet, Why an aleph, for Emet = truth. (Im aware of the midrashim on the first letter)

Comment: One source in favor of what @Gabriel wrote: https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Aggadah%2C_Genesis.1.25.1?vhe=Midrash_Aggadah,_ed._Buber,_Vienna,_1894.&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: However, here's two sources I know of that seemingly disagree: https://www.sefaria.org/Etz_Yosef_on_Bereishit_Rabbah.30.8.9?vhe=Midrash_Rabbah_with_Etz_Yosef,_Warsaw,_1867&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en and I once saw a Midrash that goes into detail about how Man was originally meant to live a long time and then die... but unfortunately I cannot find it right now.

Comment: @Gabriel where did you see that?